# How to change about:blank on window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, window

Hi is it possible to remove the About: blank on a new open window?
Because I was creating a new window for my application pop up and will create some content on it. I have a simple sample below.
My problem is there is "about: blank" on the URL is it possible to remove this?
[image]

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write('<html><head> <title>Sample</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/newsCSSWindow.css"></head><body>');
        myWindow.document.write("Sample Window");
        myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Mozilla Developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Description) first parameter of open() will be a url.  If url is an empty string, then a new blank, empty window (URL about:blank) is created with the default toolbars of the main window. also  URLs won't load immediately. When window.open() returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.

Comment: Can we not disable it or hide?

Comment: we can only replace with other url but cannot disable or hide

Comment: i guess there's no solution for me on that request. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can not be removed but you can change the text **"about: blank"** to your current URL by putting space in first position or by giving specific path.

```
  var win = window.open(
                            "http://www.domainname.ext/path.png",
                            "DescriptiveWindowName",
                            "width=420,height=230,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1"
                            );
```